# How to join database tables using cakePHP?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Now I have been trying to tackle this issue for a few hours now, and I been trying google and the documentation and read it over and over, but I can't seem to understand it.

Let me try explain what im doing, but simplify the project, assume I am making a blog with **cakePHP**. I got this 3 tables to make it simple we use only the needed fields.

```
Table: posts
Desc: This table store all our posts
Fields:
postid - Identifier for the post
title - The posts title

Table: sections
Desc: this table contains categories
Fields:
sectionid - Identifier
sectionname - Name

Table: postlinks 
Desc: this table store relations between posts and categories.
Fields:
postid – Post ID to determine what post is linked to what section
sectionid – Section ID to determine the section this post belong to
```

Let me now try explain what I want to achieve with cakePHP by showing an example with regular php and SQL codes:

(Note this code was written up on the go and might not work but it should give you an idea on what I'm trying to do)

```
<?php
/**
 *Block of code to fetch all posts
 */
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{
 $postid = $rows['postid'];
 /** Join postlinks and sections **/
 $sql = “SELECT sections.*, postlinks.* FROM postlinks
  INNER JOIN sections
  ON postlinks.sectionid = sections.sectionid
  WHERE postlinks.postid = '$postid'”;

 $query = mysql_query($sql);

 print “-- TITLE --”;
 print “-- CONTENT --”;

 print “Posted in “;

 /** Loop all categories **/
 while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
 {
  print $rows['sectionname'] . “ “;
 }
}
?>
```

And now I will try explain with words what I am trying to achieve:

When a visitor is browsing the web page, and enter the blog part of the site, I wish to list X latest posts, and this posts can be put in more than one category, and we will store all category links in a separate table, and here is where I am stuffed, I can manage to get the links out but I can't seem to join the tables and loop out the name.

Hope someone can shed some light on this problem I got with either point me in the right direction and/or show me an example code.

As mentioned I have been reading the documentation, and I have attempted searching for the answer but

Comment: What you're talking about is a run-off-the-mill [hasAndBelongsToMany relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) between Posts and Categories. Have you already set that up correctly? If so, please explain again what the problem is. I couldn't figure it out from your description.

Comment: I agree with deceze. I would advice you to follow cakephp conventions: http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions.

Answer (score 0):

association is implement as a join in cakephp.
please follow the concept for HABTM i.e "Has And Belongs To Many"
make a declaration in you model association.

declare the association in your cakephp query.

recursive -> -1 or 0 or 1 or 2

to Know more about association please visit this link [enter link description here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)